# Is it possible to show the ccnet production environment dashboard in staging(other) environments ccnet dashboard?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

I have two deployment environments production and test for my project. I have kept the code repository in test environment and i have a branch 'release' in the repository which has the stable code which i will deploy in the production environment. I have installed ccnet in test environment and it takes code from the trunk and hosts in the test environment. I can see the ccnet webdashboard in the test environment.

I want to setup ccnet in the production environment also, but i fear whether users may be able to see the production environment's ccnet webdashboard. I don't want it to happen. instead i should be able to see the production server details in the test environment ccnet dashboard. there when i click on force button, it should take the code from release branch and deploy it in production env.

am i too ambitious or is it possible to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible. Install ccnet on prod, but not the web dashboard part. Then in test configure the dashboard to connect to the ccnet service on the prod server. Configure the firewall on prod to allow connections from the web dashboard on the test server, but Dont allow connections on that port from the Internet.